# Fresh Arch install: Lots of "could not resolve host" errors

Tags: arch-linux, internet, pacman

I've just installed Arch. My computer is connected to my router/modem via Ethernet cable.

I just logged in and tried using `pacman` to install a package but got a bunch of "could not resolve host" errors.

[image]

When I run `ping google.com` it sometimes works but other times gives this error: `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Output of `ip addr`
[image]

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`
[image]

Comment: It's clear you have DNS issues. Check `/etc/resolv.conf`. It not that, then I would say you have no network setup.

Comment: Use `Server = http://166.78.229.131/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch` to check if it is DNS issue. This is the mirror name http://mirror.rackspace.com

Comment: @Bib What should I be looking for in that file? It exists and I will add to my question the contents of it.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan Can you tell me, step by step, what you're asking me to do? I tried typing your idea in command line and got "Server: command not found" error.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: OP is stuck in tty. There's nothing else he can do really.

Comment: @Username Write the `Server = http://166.78.229.131/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch` line instead of `Include = /etc/pacman.s/mirrorlist` and see if `sudo pacman -Syu` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have both dhcpcd and network-manager installed. Having two packages to manage your network causes conflicts. Try uninstalling one of them.

Comment: I added that line to the bottom of the file but still get the same error when running `ping google.com`

Comment: Check if you have your hostname set up(`/etc/hostname`)

Comment: Also try `ip addr` to check if your interface is up.

Comment: I have the name in `/etc/hostname`, though when I run `hostname` in terminal it says "command not found"

Comment: I added the output of ‘ip addr’

Comment: Try `sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up`

Comment: I just realized the cable connecting my laptop with my modem came unplugged. I have updated my question with the correct output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132503/discussion-between-username-and-gagan).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause of this problem is that `systemd-resolved` wasn't running(inactive). So try to check its status first:

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved
```

If you see that the value of `Active` field is **inactive**, you need to start it:

```
systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

Comment: this was the one that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According `ip addr`, it appears you have not connected and authenticated to a wireless network yet.

Use `iwctl` to connect to a network:

```
iwctl --passphrase <passphrase> station wlp1s0 connect <SSID>
```

Comment: I will try this. But why won't my internet work even when connected to my modem via Ethernet cable?

Comment: @Username there could be a driver problem since your Ethernet device does not show up in `ip`. You can check `dmesg` to see if there are any errors. If there isn't anything, you should check your BIOS settings to make sure Ethernet isn't disabled.

Comment: I just realized I accidentally unplugged the Ethernet cable. I plugged it back in and edited my question with the correct `ip addr` output. Still getting the same errors though.

Comment: @Username could be a DHCP issue as your Ethernet device is not being assigned an IP address by your router. Check your router settings if DHCP is correctly setup and if any other connected computers are being assigned IP addresses.

Comment: When I log into my router admin page, I can see my laptop listed as connected to it, with an IP address. The laptop's hostname is also present.

Comment: @Username I see that you have two DHCP clients running (`dhcpcd` and NetworkManager). This can cause conflicts so only one should be running. Disable `dhcpcd`: `sudo systemctl disable --now dhcpcd.service`

Answer (score 0):

My particular issue was not having installed `linux-firmware` before rebooting without the flash ISO. The wireless device was missing altogether from `ip addr`. The solution was to :

1. Boot from the arch iso.
2. Use `iwctl` to connect to the wireless network
3. After having installed a working network connection `arch-chroot` into my installation (mount it again if needed).
4. `pacman -S linux-firmware`